# jooq @NotNull validation for AutoIncrement

Tags: spring, jooq, javax

I am using JOOQ with Spring. I have table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE city (
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC))
  ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

From this table JOOQ generates

```
@NotNull
public UInteger getId() {
    return this.id;
}
```

This will fail Javax validation @Valid.

There was google group [Link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jooq-user/cbTYy9e523c/t2jqg8U2CAAJ) and it was said it was fixed [Link](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5128).

I am using JOOQ 3.9.1.

Am I doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, it seems that fix [#5128](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5128) (which you've linked) only works for those databases that report identity columns as defaulted columns to jOOQ-meta.

An additional fix will be required to exclude also "non-defaulted" identity columns from having this annotation generated:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6401